# Can I change the level of a message logged by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, logging

Our Spring-based microservice sometimes fails to connect to its eventing service for a couple of minutes. This is okay from an application point of view, as we have several retries and fallbacks in place that take care of this. Each failed connection attempt results in an ERROR log written by the class org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer. Is it possible to configure Spring such that this log message would be written with a lower log level, such as WARN?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: Your options that I can see are to live with it, suppress error logging from that class, or fork the library and make the change.  I would NOT recommend the latter.  Is there no error handling hooks in the library that would avoid the logging?

Comment: @Taylor I didn't see any hooks that would allow to intercept and suppress the standard error handling. The library throws exceptions that we react upon with retries and fallbacks. That's actually good enough for us. However, before it throws those exceptions, the library applies its standard behavior and logs the temporary connection failure as an ERROR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jens mentioned this is not possible since the level at which a message is logged is given by the actual function call.

So, if Spring (or any other library or even your own code, really) has something like:

```java
public void connect() {
    try(establishConnection()) {
        // ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to establish connection");
    }
```

you'll notice that the logging is always done at the `error` level, since that is what is being invoked.

The only recourse you have in this case is to set the log level of the class to `OFF` if your given logging implementation supports it (the default, Logback, does). For example:

```yaml
# application.yml
logging.level:
  org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer: OFF
```

However, there's really no reason to do this unless you are getting absolutely swamped by these log messages (and even then, just filter them in your Dashboard). Error logs exist for a reason.

Alternatively, I *suppose* you could also do some hacky trickery using AspectJ to change the level something is logged at if you *really, really needed to*, but I doubt this applies in this case.

Lastly, you can fork the library and link your own Jar files into your application. But I doubt this maintenance burden is worth it in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions.  We will definitely not go down the hacker path there, that's not worth it. We use alerts like "> 20 ERRORs during last 24h" to identify issues in our deployments. Those logs trigger these alerts too often, with no need to. I had hoped for some Spring configuration magic that would allow reclassifying the log levels. Without that, we'll seek for a way to adjust our alerts to ignore a certain portion of these not-so important logs.

Comment: As some of the other comments mentioned, some Spring components do allow setting a configuration flag to slightly alter log output (i.e. logging something at `WARN` using an `if/else` somewhere in there). Perhaps you could open a GitHub issue on the relevant Spring Repo or even provide the fix yourself, if you feel like it's warranted for a more general audience.

Comment: @Florian One more thing, since I had a similar issue a while back. If you are up to initializing the beans yourself, you could implement a liveness check for the external service and halt initialization of the JMS components until you are sure that the external component *should* be reachable. This would minimize the amount of false positives during startup, though at the cost of slightly increased startup time (for retries/backoff).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the level at which a message is logged is given by the actual function call. .

So, if Spring has something like:

```
public void connect() {
try(establishConnection()) {
    // ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Failed to establish connection");
}
```

you'll notice that the **logging is always done at the error level**, since that is what is being invoked.

What you can do is to **set the log level of the class to OFF** :

```
# application.yml
```

logging.level:
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer: OFF